# Windows desktop ScreenMarker

Tags: c#, java, c++, .net, windows

I want to make a Tool that enables the user to interact with Windows, giving the user the ability of, writting, making shapes, take region screenshots, erasing, etc on top of any window and at the same time be able to itneract with the same window if the selection tool is activated.

What language would you recommend I use? I was thinking of using JAVA with JNI or .NET with c# or c++. What would be the easiest way to approach this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I made something similar once that allowed the user to press F7 to go into "painting mode" and then scribble on the screen. When F7 was pressed again, it stayed on top, but interaction came back. The biggest thing for that was one window (transparency 1) for capturing input, and one (color key) for drawing on that sat over top of everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ease of coding, I would recommend using .NET with C#.

There are lots of hooks into the Win32 graphics system which are available in the .NET API.  Of course, it would only work on the Windows operating system, but it seems you're ok with this.

Comment: +1 @RobSiklos, off-course if one is sure about `Windows` as only application environment than .NET is the best choice..

Comment: Thanks, I thought c# would be the best approach. Do you know of any good c# pages to research on this development?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536141/how-to-draw-directly-on-the-windows-desktop-c and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905783/how-to-effectively-draw-on-desktop-in-c.