# Draw on desktop wallpaper

Tags: c#, windows-7, wallpaper, aero

Any way to draw on the wallpaper in windows 7 with aero enabled? I saw the post for doing it in xp/7 without aero but I'd rather keep it enabled if possible. I also tried the windows 8 approach but that doesn't seem to work in 7 and I can't figure out the correct messages to send.

EDIT:
[How to effectively draw on desktop in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905783/how-to-effectively-draw-on-desktop-in-c) only works when aero is disabled. When it's enabled the icons and wallpaper are merged so it's impossible to just draw on the wallpaper. The personalization window seems to do it when fading between wallpapers but I've been unable to figure out what to send so far. Replicating the messages Spy++ logs just seems to freeze the wallpaper so it's unable to be changed until explorer is restarted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to effectively draw on desktop in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905783/how-to-effectively-draw-on-desktop-in-c)

Comment: Another similar questions: [How to draw directly on the Windows Desktop, C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536141/how-to-draw-directly-on-the-windows-desktop-c) and [Draw on screen without a form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14385838/draw-on-screen-without-form)

Comment: @Matias Cicero In aero the background and icons are merged, so just drawing on it will draw on top of the icons too. The personalization window sends some messages that spawn a workerw thread behind the icons, but like I said I can't figure out how to replicate that.

Comment: @MatiasCicero: The other answers are exactly the same, so why do you think they'd help if the first one didn't already?