# Transparent, clickable through, Text Displayable form c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Hello I want to make form application that will be full screen transparent and clickable throught but it will display text. I dont even need form if there is way to display text on top of the screen (if some more apps will be open)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iaWo.jpg)

Like so.

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of Application, Web Application, Console Application etc. , What have you done so far?  I suggest reading [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)
you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have whole application (Windows form). That application should only display label.

Comment: there are existing questions with good answers, and a lot of google results. [start here...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2905783/1132334)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            var F = new Form
            {
                BackColor = Color.Black,
                TransparencyKey = Color.Black,
                Bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds,
                FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None,
            };

            var L = new Label
            {
                AutoSize = false,
                Text="Hello, World!",
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                ForeColor = Color.White,
                Font = new Font("Consolas", 26),
                TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            };

            F.Controls.Add(L);
            Application.Run(F);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you.