# How do I create a fully transparent winform in C# that is interactive?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to create a form in C# that is fully transparent, but will not allow clicks to go through it to the other windows below. 
I have found two methods that were promising, but did not achieve the results I wanted.

The first is by setting the background color and transparency key to the same value. This gives me the transparent form, but clicking goes through.

```
this.BackColor = Color.Red;
this.TransparencyKey = Color.Red;
```

The other thing I tried is to set the opacity of the form to 1%. This creates the effects I wanted - almost. I get a 99% transparent form, but there is a slight color alteration to whatever is underneath the form. Since the app I am making is meant to be used in color-sensitive context (graphic design and such), even a tiny alteration of the colors is unacceptable. So I turn to you, dear SO. Can this be done?

Comment: What do you want to do? Just throw an overlay on the form so that nothing can be clicked or interacted with?

Comment: @Yuck I think his question is fairly clear, he just wants to make his form totally transparent but user can interact with that form, not only clicking but also other actions such as mouse entering, mouse leaving, key press, ... I guess so, however at least he wants his totally transparent form to clickable.

Comment: I don't understand this question.. if you set opacity to 0% you won't see it, but then how will you interact with it?!

Comment: @Alan you should associate more, like as you stand in front of a glass, you may not see it, but you can touch it. If you know it is right in front of you, you may know how to avoid hitting it inadvertently, which may make you hurt .

Comment: @Yuck I want to make an app that will allow you to draw over any other window. Therefore it's important that when you click to draw, you don't press whatever button is underneath.

Comment: This is a screenshot of what I am trying to do:

[link](http://imgur.com/KmVwyxc,SQ0YAi3)

The first screenshot is set at 50% opacity, the second at 99%. The second screenshot might appear alright at first, but it slightly alters the colors of the underlying window.

Comment: @Ermir Thanks, that clarification is hugely helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution, and I am sharing it with you guys as well.

The answer was quite simple: I set: `this.TransparencyKey = Color.Lime;`

And then I used a 1x1px Lime PNG as the background image. This also has the added benefit of not obscuring the form border and title bar. I will remove them later, but at the moment, it's useful to know where the form is located.

Comment: That doesn't work for me, clickthrough still happens. Perhaps that was a bug that is now "fixed" in recent C#. However that leaves me with no solution to transparent controls with clickthrough.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to this completely by accident.

I wanted a click through transparent window and got it by using the answer in this SO question:

[C# cursor highlighting/follower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622612/c-sharp-cursor-highlighting-follower/2624564#2624564)

That answer uses a transparency filter of LightGreen, but I thought that I might need to use that Color so I changed it to AliceBlue and click through stopped working. I switched back to LightGreen and it started working again.

Comment: Thank you for this!. I was having a similar issue and this is what resolved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to capture mouse actions on the transparent form, you can try just capturing mouse actions system-wide (clicks, moves) and handle them as you need.

Comment: this is not really what the OP's want can do. For example, if you click on a transparent window, you will think the window you see is the window being clicked however it's not. If using your solution, the window you see is surely the window being clicked. Of course if you have more code to handle that case (and many more issues). A totally transparent window is much more interesting.

Comment: I have found the solution, and I am sharing it with you guys as well. The answer was quite simple: I set:
  
    

    `this.TransparencyKey = Color.Lime;`  

And then I used a 1x1px Lime PNG as the background image. This also has the added benefit of not obscuring the form border and title bar. I will remove them later, but at the moment, it's useful to know where the form is located.

Comment: @Ermir I've experienced with making a window totally transparent and still be clickable but that window was rendered by an Aero-enabled UI OS like Windows 7, it may not work on other OSs such as Windows XP.

Comment: @Ermir post that as an answer, so it's easier to see for others looking at this question

Comment: @Ermir is color `Lime` the only one which works? what about other colors?

Comment: Any color works, just as long as the RGB values of the transparency key and the 1x1px png match. @jszigeti I can't post a solution to my own question until 8 hours have passed. This is a brand new Stack Overflow account.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in the following way (assuming the drawn-on form keeps maximized. If not, see the next paragraphs below):

- Take screenshot of the current screen.
- Create a form and use the screenshot as the background image.
- Remove form title from the form, simply make it as a panel.

While the solution above solves what you want, you need to answer the question:

- How will the user close the form he's drawing on?

### If the form needs to be resized-moved - complicated version

However, if you want to resize this form (just noticed your edit with the new screenshots), then you need to cut the part of the taken screenshot and show it as the background of the form. But this goes farther then: you need to do it every time the form is resized or moved.

I personally would take the first (simpler) approach.

Comment: I have already found a far simpler solution than either of those. I can't answer my own question, as this is a brand new SO account. But I have posted the solution as a comment to @alex 's answer

Comment: I thought in that case the background is still clickable. If not, nice solution indeed! good luck!

Comment: @Ermir your solution doesn't work, the form is transparent with no surprise but it's not interactive, I can click everything behind it.

Answer (score 1):

You can set hook to catch the mouse events.

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern int SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, HookProc lpfn, IntPtr hInstance, int threadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(int idHook);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern int CallNextHookEx(int idHook, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public class MouseStruct
    {
        public Point pt;
        public int hwnd;
        public int wHitTestCode;
        public int dwExtraInfo;
    }

    public delegate int HookProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam); 

    private int hHook;
    public const int WH_MOUSE_LL = 14;
    public static HookProc hProc;

    public int SetHook()                                        
    {
        hProc = new HookProc(MouseHookProc);
        hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, hProc, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
        return hHook;
    }
    public void UnHook()                                        
    {
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook);
    }
    //callback function, invoked when there is an mouse event
    private int MouseHookProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)              
    {
        var MyMouseStruct = (MouseStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MouseStruct));
        if (nCode < 0)
        {
            return CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);    
        }
        else
        {
            switch wParam{
                case (IntPtr)513:
                    //click
                    //do whatever you want
                case (IntPtr)512:
                    //move
                case (IntPtr)514:
                    //release
                default:
            }
            Cursor.Position = MyMouseStruct.pt;
            //stop the event from passed to other windows.
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

More details at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644988%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).